# Mean Row of Matrix

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use `mean(A,1)` to get the mean row of a matrix `A`, but am getting an error.

For example, try running the command `mean(eye(3), 1)`.
This gives the error `no method mean(Array{Float64,2},Int32)`.

The only documentation I can find for the `mean` function is here:
http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.1/stdlib/base/#statistics

> ```
> mean(v[, region])
> ```
>
> Compute the mean of whole array `v`, or optionally along the dimensions in `region`.

What is the `region` parameter?

**EDIT**: for Julia 0.7 and higher, write this as `mean(v, dims=1)`.

Comment: It must be something with your installation, `mean(eye(3),1)` works just fine here.

Comment: @juliohm I have since discovered that it was something wrong with JuliaStudio (a Julia IDE) in particular. The statement works fine when run directly through julia.bat.

Comment: I'll make my comment into an answer so that you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be something with your installation, `mean(eye(3),1)` works just fine here.

Comment: what does it mean  : mean(x,2). x is a matrix of 3 by 3. ?

Comment: @samtzaurtis I don't understand your question, please type every piece in Julia before you ask.

Answer (score 7):

```
julia> using Statistics
julia> A = [[1 2 3];[ 4 5 6]]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

# Column means
julia> mean(A, dims=1)
1×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.5  3.5  4.5

# Row means
julia> mean(A, dims=2)
2×1 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0
 5.0
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.

Comment: the depriciations and modifications of all kids are really confusing.