# More elegant way of finding the mean of the rows in a matrix with julia

Tags: matrix, julia, mean

I have a 3x55 matrix of `int`s. I want to center each row around its mean. This gets the right answer, but it's ugly:

```
row_mean = mean(points,[2])
points[1,:] = points[1,:] - row_mean[1]
points[2,:] = points[2,:] - row_mean[2]
points[3,:] = points[3,:] - row_mean[3]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does this work? `points = points - mean(points, 1)`

Comment: possible duplicate: [Mean Row of Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148013/mean-row-of-matrix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED:

You can use the element-wise minus function, `.-`, to calculate the difference between each row and its mean value:

```
points .- mean(points, 2)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10156839)

Comment: @ElGavilan I have edited the answer to clear any request for clarification.

Comment: It seems to me that it correctly provides an answer to the original question,

Comment: Thanks @RezaAfzalan that about did it. There seems to be some precision difference between the two answers though. Tiny like -2.32831e-10. Wondering what the difference is..