# computing mean over a dimension in Julia

Tags: julia

I just downloaded Julia 1.0 and been trying to play with it. One annoying thing is that most of the examples that I found online deal with version 0.6 and it seems it is a big change between the versions.

So I am trying to compute the mean along a particular dimension of a matrix. I do the following:

```
a = rand(10, 5)
```

Now I can do

```
mean(a)
```

but not:

```
mean(a, 1)
```

Looking at the question here: [Mean Row of Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148013/mean-row-of-matrix), it seems that this was working in the older versions. What is the Julia 1.0 way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument to `mean` (and several other similar functions) became a keyword argument in Julia v0.7 and above. You should use

```
mean(a, dims = 1)
```

See also: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/psa-use-julia-0-7-if-you-are-upgrading/13321

Comment: Nice answer and I'll be checking out that link.